I want automatically to execute the cronjob in node.js at exactly last day of the month
const sendReport = new CronJob(
  "0 0 28-31 * *",
  async function () {
      try {
        console.log("Running a task every minute in sending Reports");
        await sendMail();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error running Sending Email:", error);
      }
  },
  null,
  true,
  "UTC"
);

On this one "0 0 28-31 * " I assigned it like this temporarily but how do I make it, will send only on the last day of the month, I already tried using crontab but it does not work on my code, Please help me to on how should I do with this?

You don't need to change the cron expression.
You can check the date in node.js function like:
const sendReport = new CronJob(
  "0 0 28-31 * *",
  async function () {
    const today = new Date();
    const tomorrow = new Date(today);
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

    // Check if tomorrow's date is the 1st of the next month
    if (tomorrow.getDate() === 1) {
      try {
        console.log("Running task to send reports on the last day of the month");
        await sendMail();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error running Sending Email:", error);
      }
    }
  },
  null,
  true,
  "UTC"
);


I tried it like this "const sendReport = new CronJob(
"0 0 28-31 * *",
async function () {
const tomorrow = moment().add(1, "day");
const isLastDayOfMonth = tomorrow.month() !== moment().month();
if (isLastDayOfMonth) {
try {
console.log("Running a task every minute in sending Reports");
await sendMail();
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error running Sending Email:", error);
}
}else{
console.log("Not the end of the month to send a Reports");
}
},
null,
true,
"UTC"
);" does it makes different ?

you just checked the month value if it's different from current one after one day, so it's also a way to achieve your expectation.
